# Changing background of a Stack in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm creating an application for fun to learn ruby and shoes, but it seems that I cannot accomplish what I'm trying to do...

I have a stack with some text inside and, under certain circumstances, I want to change the background of that stack, but for some reason all the text inside the stack is deleted.
How can I avoid that? I just want to change the background color.

Sample code to show the problem:

```
Shoes.app do

    @first_stack = stack do
        background orange
        @title = title "my title"
        @subtitle = subtitle "my subtitle"
    end 

    button ("change background") {
        @first_stack.background gold
    }

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems background creates a fill which means your text is still there just nested under the fill. Here is a work around

```
Shoes.app do 
  def change_color(back)
    @first_stack.clear
    @first_stack.background back
    @first_stack.title @title
    @first_stack.subtitle @subtitle
  end
  @first_stack = stack do
    background orange
    @title = title "my title"
    @subtitle = subtitle "my subtitle"
  end 

  button ("change background") do 
    change_color(gold)
  end
end
```

This just clears the first stack and recreates it with a new color. Still looking into a more eloquent method.

**EDIT**

Found a solution:

```
Shoes.app do
  @first_stack = stack do
      @fs_background = background orange
      @title = title "my title"
      @subtitle = subtitle "my subtitle"
  end 
  button ("change background") do
     @fs_background.remove
     @first_stack.before(@title) {@fs_background = background gold}
  end
end
```

This  will work the way you want as it places a background layer on top of the original background layer but before `@title`.

Comment: Ok, so the background is not a 'back' but just a layer and I should place it before the first element of my stack to make it in the right z-index.

Comment: by the way your code works even removing the 'background:gold' clause from the @first_stack declaration.
I'm looking into removing the old background too, as I understand it will still be there if I do it this way.
Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You could try @first_stack.background.remove. The Z-index is set based on call ordering so no matter where you place the background you will have to call before or it will fill over top of other elements.

Comment: Already tried the remove, but it doesn't work...
About the background, I think the name is deceiving, they should have called that just something like 'fill_layer' because it's not on the back (even if it's written in a note on the docs)

Comment: remove works if you make the background an `instance_variable` see edited version. If you comment out the before portion you can see the layer is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you make the background the first element:

```
Shoes.app do
  @f = stack do
    background blue
    title "my title"
    subtitle "my subtitle"
  end 
  button ("change background") do
     @f.children.first.remove
     @f.before(@f.children.first) {
       background gold
     }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in Shoes3.3.1 you can do it that way

```
Shoes.app do
    @first_stack = stack do
        background orange
        @title = title "my title"
        @subtitle = subtitle "my subtitle"
    end 

    button ("change background") {
        @first_stack.contents[0].fill = gold
        @first_stack.refresh_slot
    }
end
```